# Тире перед "это"

Tags: пунктуация

Почему, если в вопросительных предложениях стоит тире, то и в утвердительных оно необходимо?
Примеры:

> — Дмитрий — это ты?
> — Да, Дмитрий — это я!

> — "Ремонт" — это ты сказал?

— Ага, "ремонт" — это я сказал!

Comment: Дмитрий, поясните, пожалуйста, это один диалог или два?

Comment: К сожалению (или к счастью), это два разных диалога.